# Like Wildcard from column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following data stored in a table:

```
Table.Wildcard
-------------
a%
%b%
%c
```

When I run this statement, I get no results:

```
Declare @Var varchar = 'abc'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Wildcard LIKE @Var
```

I tried this, again I get no results:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Replace(Wildcard,'[%]','%') LIKE @Var
```

Not sure what else to try. Suggestions?

Comment: I've never even though about it being placed before the like... didn't know it wouldn't work great question and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch it

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE @Var LIKE Wildcard
```

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards are only accepted in the second parameter of the Like clause.  So the string with wild cards needs to be second.

```
Select * From Table Where @Var Like Wildcard
```